# Can you intersect objects created in AR-mode using raycaster on A-Frame?

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, webxr

I am making a web application that stacks blocks in AR-mode of A-Frame.
A newly created block object in AR-mode does not respond to Raycaster.
I want to know where the block and Raycaster intersect.
It reacts to the originally placed object (Hello a-frame object).

code in glitch
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/piquant-polyester-monday

Comment: Hey did you manage to get it working?

Comment: Raycaster worked. But I haven't changed anything ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raycaster worked. But I haven't changed anything ...
It may be my misunderstanding. Sorry.
Close this question.